# Merging in R: 1 row missing after merge

Tags: r, merge

I have a dataframe movielens:

```
str(u.data)
'data.frame':   100000 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ userID   : int  196 186 22 244 166 298 115 253 305 6 ...
 $ movieID  : int  242 302 377 51 346 474 265 465 451 86 ...
 $ rating   : int  3 3 1 2 1 4 2 5 3 3 ...
 $ timestamp: int  881250949 891717742 878887116 880606923 886397596 884182806 881171488 891628467 886324817 883603013 ...
```

and

```
str(u.item)
'data.frame':   1681 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ unknown    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Action     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Adventure  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Animation  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Childrens  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ Comedy     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ Crime      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Documentary: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Drama      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Fantasy    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Film-Noir  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Horror     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Musical    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Mystery    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Romance    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sci-Fi     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Thriller   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ War        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Western    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ movieID    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

The number of row of `u.data` is 100.000

```
nrow(u.data)
100000
```

And

```
nrow(u.item)
[1] 1681
```

Then, I want to merge them:

```
all_data = u.data
all_data = merge(all_data, u.item, by = "movieID")
```

But the merged data has only 99.999 rows

```
nrow(all_data)
[1] 99999
```

Did I did something wrong while merging these two data frames?

Comment: `max(moviedID)` in `u.item` > `max(movieID)` in `u.data` maybe. Or the opposite with the minimum?

Comment: may be `all.x=T` in `merge` needed?

Comment: @Pascal Yes, you are right. I fixed it and now it is okay.

Comment: @Batanicheck You mean `all.x = TRUE`.  Try the following in your console: `T <- FALSE` versus `TRUE <- FALSE`.  I actually broke code before by calling a transposed matrix `T`. Don't be that coder ;)

Answer (score 0):

This happens if `min(u.data$movieID) < min(u.item$movieID)` or if `max(u.data$movieID) > max(u.item$movieID)`. Example for the latter:

```
# max(u.data$movieID) = 10
u.data <- data.frame(movieID = 1:10, NAME = LETTERS[1:10])
dim(u.data)
# [1] 10  2

# max(u.item$movieID) = 11
u.item <- data.frame(movieID = c(1:9,11), name = letters[c(1:9,11)])
dim(u.item)
# [1] 10  2

out <- merge(u.data, u.item, by = "movieID")
dim(out)
# [1] 9 3

# check if all elements of u.item$movieID exist in u.data$movieID
is.element(u.data$movieID, u.item$movieID)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Suggested by Batanichek:

```
out <- merge(u.data, u.item, by = "movieID", all.x = TRUE)
dim(out)
# [1] 10  3
```